# XYZ update on cloudpoints- QGIS GUI

Tags: qgis, point, update

I have imported data as cloudpoints into QGIS with xcoord, ycoord, depth and elevation.

In some cases I've picked the wrong value for the "Z field" when importing the data, some layers have depth and other elevations... and I just realized when I watched a vertical view of my points with the 'Section Manager' tool, check image.

Is it possible that once the layer is imported I can update the 'Z field' or the zcoord of my layer? I've tried using the Field calculator, multiplying by -1 the depth, but the Z field doesn't update itself... so I have to import from zero the data, and it's tedious.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that the file you imported is not editable.
Export your data as GeoPackage, then add it as a new layer, and go on with the creation of a new field in `Attribute table` -> `Field calculator`.

A suggestion for the formula could be:

`-1 * abs( "imported_z" )`

which would yield all-negative values.

[image]

Comment: as i said before, i already tried this but it doesn't update the elevation or the 'z field'. I can see still the points above ground level (as in the photo). I even created another field, but i don't know how to tell qgis to take a different zcoord.

Comment: it would be like, how do i tell qgis to take one column instead of another one for the 'z field' or the zcoord?

Comment: "I already tried this but it doesn't update the elevation or the 'z field'": Have you tried exporting/reimporting the file as suggested in the answer? And creating a new field, instead of updating the existing `Z` field?

Comment: "how do i tell qgis to take one column instead of another one for the 'z field' or the zcoord?" see the screenshot I posted, in particular, make sure to check the `Create a new field` flag

Comment: "Have you tried exporting/reimporting the file as suggested in the answer? And creating a new field, instead of updating the existing Z field?"

yes i can do it manually, and that works. But when i have 50 files like that it's time consuming

Comment: Now I see, not what I understood from the original question. You have many files and want to "correct" their values upon import. AFAIK that cannot be done, but you can write a script to do so, and batch it across all imported files, or edit the files externally (for example with `awk`). Also, please: edit the question with these information so as to help others better understand.